# Identity Membership roles ASP.NET 4.5 MVC Adding Claims based Roles

Tags: entity-framework-4, code-first, claims-based-identity, asp.net-mvc-5

I have used the sample given in https://github.com/rustd/AspnetIdentitySample to create a custom User profile data.

However, I am not sure how to assign roles to the newly registered user upon sign up. It looks like it uses .net 4.5 Claims based roles. Also it uses Code First - migrations and creates the necessary Membership tables like Roles, UserRoles.

I am looking to add a new role to Roles tables and assign this role to a new user with an entry into the UserRoles table.

Help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you want to create role and add new user to it, you may modify your Register method as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);
                    WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);

                        Roles.CreateRole("Role A");// add "Role A"
                        Roles.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, "Role A"); // user in role A 


                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
                }
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: Tried that earlier. Doesn't help. Gives "Role Manager Feature has not been enabled' The Role Manager feature has not been enabled.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderException: The Role Manager feature has not been enabled.

Comment: @user2690280 just add <roleManager enabled="true" /> to web.config

Comment: tried adding <roleManager enabled="true" /> but doesn't help either. if you look at the sample project ( https://github.com/rustd/AspnetIdentitySample ) there is a separate membership db that handles the users. so there must something with membership provider thing.

Comment: @user2690280 if you still don't have asp membership tables in your database do following: Add Aspnet membership tables to your database. Navigate to the wizard(C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework[framework version]\aspnet_regsql) and launch it. It will run special wizzard, which helps to add tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try IdentityConfig.Roles.AddUserToRole? Make sure the role is in the Role table of the DefaultConnection. I assume you're working off the demo they released at that conference just before BUILD this summer? Andrey's answer relies on the old membership system, with the web configuration utility, I believe?

Answer (score 0):

var rm = new RoleManager(new RoleStore(newApplicationDbContext()));

rm.Create(new IdentityRole("Admin"));

rm.Create(new IdentityRole("Finance"));

UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Admin");